# Ruby on Rails: Unable to update table entry on some occasions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have an app that allows a user to enter and edit projects in a table called Projects. One of the fields allows them to check technologies for that project. They are stored in a separate table called Technols, and the relationship between the tables is called Projecttechnols.

As an example, I have a Project X, which has many technologies, tech1, tech2 and tech3. If I go into edit the project, I can remove or add the technolgies to the project, and update the project at will. My problem starts though, when I try to take all the projects out of project. If I try this, nothing is changed, and the technologies stay the same.

I have no problem creating a new project with no technologies, and I can go back into that project and edit by inserting technologies, but if I go back to edit it again with technologies added, and try to remove them all. Nothing happens.

**Here are my new, edit, create and update actions from the project controller:**

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
  @technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])

  @all_technols = Technol.all

  @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @project }
  end
end

# GET /projects/1/edit
def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build

  puts @project.inspect
  puts @project.technols.inspect
end

# POST /projects
# POST /projects.json
def create  
  @project = Project.new(params[:project])
  @project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
  @project.role = params[:new_role] unless params[:new_role].blank?
  @project.industry = params[:new_industry] unless params[:new_industry].blank?
  @project.business_div = params[:new_business_div] unless params[:new_business_div].blank?

  if !params[:technols].nil?
    params[:technols][:id].each do |tech|
      if !tech.empty?
        @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => tech) 
      end
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PUT /projects/1
# PUT /projects/1.json
# PUT /projects/1
# PUT /projects/1.json
def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])

  puts @project.inspect
  puts @project.technols.inspect

  params['project'][:client] = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
  params['project'][:role] = params[:new_role] unless params[:new_role].blank?
  params['project'][:industry] = params[:new_industry] unless params[:new_industry].blank?
  params['project'][:business_div] = params[:new_business_div] unless params[:new_business_div].blank?              

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**Here is my edit view for the tech bit:**

```
<div class="tech" STYLE="text-align: left;">
  <b>Technologies:</b>
  <style>
    .split { text-align:left; }
  </style>   

  <p>
    <ul>
      <% for technol in Technol.all %> 
        <li class="split"> 
          <%= check_box_tag "project[technol_ids][]", technol.id,  @project.technols.include?(technol) %> 
          <%= technol.tech %> 
        </li>
      <% end %> 
    </ul>
  </p>
```

I am new to Rails, so it might be something really simple. All help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user unchecks all `project[technol_ids][]` checkboxes, then that field doesn't appear in `params` at all. At least one checkbox must be checked to have the field be present. So hopefully you can understand why the model doesn't change any of the `projecttechnol` records.

To fix this, make sure that there is *something* stored for the param at the top of your `update` action:

```
params[:project][:technol_ids] ||= []
```

This ensures that you have an empty array if no checkboxes are checked. Passing an empty array into the model should should clear out all records that are present.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain where I was going wrong. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is any code in your update action to add/remove associations.  If params[:technol_ids] differs from what is in the database for that project, you'll need to add/remove those records accordingly.

I'd have a look at this guide -  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, 
particularly the first few examples where they are deleting and creating associations.

Comment: Why am I able to remove all but one technologies then?

Comment: Doesn't matter, this explains my problem `params[:project][:technol_ids] ||= []`